# problem with Speech Sdk 5.1?

Tags: c#, sapi

I am saving an audio file as test.wav from below

```
        SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags SpFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync;
        SpVoice Voice = new SpVoice();

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        sfd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
        sfd.Title = "Save to a wave file";
        sfd.FilterIndex = 2;
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

        SpeechStreamFileMode SpFileMode = SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite;

        SpFileStream SpFileStream = new SpFileStream();
        SpFileStream.Open(sfd.FileName, SpFileMode, false);

        Voice.AudioOutputStream = SpFileStream;
        Voice.Speak(txtSpeakText.Text, SpFlags);
        Voice.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);
        SpFileStream.Close();
```

When i try to reteive the file and convert to text its different

```
        SpeechRecognitionEngine RecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
        RecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        RecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile("test.wav");
        RecognitionResult result = RecognitionEngine.Recognize();
        Grammar g = result.Grammar;
        txt_vtc.Text = result.Text;
```

Why its getting like that?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not why your problem is, but I would like to recommend you to use the [SpeechSynthesizer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596245.aspx) like the following code.

```
        using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            speechSynthesizer.SelectVoice("Please enter your TTS engine name...");
            speechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile("test.wav");
            speechSynthesizer.Speak("test");
        }
```

For using `SpeechSynthesizer Class`, you would have two advantages.

1. not to need redistribute the `Speech Sdk 5.1` to clients due to the fact already included at the `.net framework(4, 3.5, 3.0)`.
2. simpler to get the goal than you mentioned.