# C#: Google Text-to-speech Loop

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, google-translate

I'm creating a simple program that takes a string, sends it to Google's text to speech server, and downloads the text to speech in a mp3/wav file on the computer. I have the code below, but it only works with up to 100 characters (Google's limit). How can I make a loop to cut the string into 100 character parts and then save it in one mp3/wav file on the computer? I know this is possible with javascript and actionscript (as I have seen them) but how can I do this in C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();

            web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows;)");

            string encstr = string.Empty;

            string filename = "tts.mp3"; //could also be tts.wav

            string s = "This string cannot be more than 100 characters.";

            encstr = Uri.EscapeDataString(s);

            Console.WriteLine(encstr);

            web.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" + encstr, ".\\" + filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, check Google's TOS; I'm not sure such a loop would be allowed, or in fact this kind of request at all. Also, each word does have an effect on words before or after it; if you split a string in any way except after a full-stop (or question mark, etc.) you could change the way it sounds.

Comment: Why not use a real TTS engine? See Microsoft's Speech API http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/TTSinVBpackage.aspx

Comment: @configurator I understand the legality issue but I have seen this done in actionscript such as here: [http://peteshand.net/blog/index.php/actionscript-text-to-speech/](http://peteshand.net/blog/index.php/actionscript-text-to-speech/) I wanted to know if this could be done in C#. Microsoft's Speech API doesnt sound natural/good. Their Bing Speech API offers something similar to Google but again is limited to 500 characters so I run into the same problem again... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but I think the splitting is not good because TTS has word intonation as well as sentence intonation. Instead, I recommend you use [SpeechSynthesizer Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407452/problem-with-speech-sdk-5-1/6408093#6408093) with free TTS engine. However, I don't know which TTS engine is good as free and where it is. If finding goodness, I'll post it.

---

**UPDATED**

MP3 files are just concatenated without a problem, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c).

> well, before I get to concatenating the mp3 files, how would the while
>   loop look like to first get those mp3 files on the computer? if i go
>   through my loop, the tts.mp3 file would be overwritten and i would be
>   left with only the last 100 character string that was received..

You can merge the two files like the code below.
Finally, the `fs1` will get all content.

```
        string tts1 = "tts1.mp3";
        string tts2 = "tts2.mp3";
        FileStream fs1 = null;
        FileStream fs2 = null;
        try
        {
            fs1 = File.Open(tts1, FileMode.Append);
            fs2 = File.Open(tts2, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] fs2Content = new byte[fs2.Length];
            fs2.Read(fs2Content, 0, (int)fs2.Length);
            fs1.Write(fs2Content, 0, (int)fs2.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs1.Close();
            fs2.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it does have intonation. However, I should have clarified this in my original question, I do know how to use the SpeechSynthesizer Class in C# as I have used this before. I wanted to know how the loop would look like if I were to split the string in 100 character intervals and create a single mp3/wav file on the computer (regardless of intonation) from Google. The same for Microsoft's Bing translator but at 500 character intervals.

Comment: I see... so, your problem is that mp3 files concatenate together? if so, you can just concatenate them toghether without a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c

Comment: well, before I get to concatenating the mp3 files, how would the while loop look like to first get those mp3 files on the computer? if i go through my loop, the tts.mp3 file would be overwritten and i would be left with only the last 100 character string that was received..